# ILMerge woes with NHIbernate

Tags: nhibernate, sharepoint, ilmerge

Has anyone successfully merged their assembly with NHibernate v3.0?

The following command doesnt work (complains about assemblies)

```
    ..\Tools\ILMerge /log:"merge.txt" 
    /lib:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5" 
    /lib:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0" 
out:SharpArchitecture.dll lib\NHibernate.Validator.dll "lib\Fluent NHibernate\NHibernate.dll" 
/keyfile:"SharpArch.Core\SharpArch.snk"
```

It needs to target the 3.5 framework so it can run under SharePoint.

here's the log

```
ILMerge version 2.11.502.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2004-2006. All rights reserved.
ILMerge /log:merge.txt /lib:C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5 /lib:C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0 /out:SharpArchitecture.dll lib\NHibernate.Validator.dll lib\Fluent NHibernate\NHibernate.dll /keyfile:SharpArch.Core\SharpArch.snk 
Set platform to 'v2', using directory 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\..\v2.0.50727' for mscorlib.dll
Running on Microsoft (R) .NET Framework v2.0.50727
mscorlib.dll version = 2.0.0.0
The list of input assemblies is:
    lib\NHibernate.Validator.dll
    lib\Fluent NHibernate\NHibernate.dll
Trying to read assembly from the file 'C:\Dev\Dev\2010\Shared Libraries\Third Party\Sharp Architecture\lib\NHibernate.Validator.dll'.
Can not find PDB file. Debug info will not be available for assembly 'lib\NHibernate.Validator.dll'.
    Successfully read in assembly.
    There were no errors reported in NHibernate.Validator's metadata.
Trying to read assembly from the file 'C:\Dev\Dev\2010\Shared Libraries\Third Party\Sharp Architecture\lib\Fluent NHibernate\NHibernate.dll'.
    Successfully read in assembly.
    There were no errors reported in NHibernate's metadata.
Checking to see that all of the input assemblies have a compatible PeKind.
    NHibernate.Validator.PeKind = ILonly
    NHibernate.PeKind = ILonly
All input assemblies have a compatible PeKind value.
AssemblyResolver: Assembly 'NHibernate.Validator' is referencing assembly 'NHibernate'.
    AssemblyResolver: Attempting referencing assembly's directory.
    AssemblyResolver: Did not find assembly in referencing assembly's directory.
    AssemblyResolver: Attempting input directory.
    AssemblyResolver: Did not find assembly in input directory.
    AssemblyResolver: Attempting user-supplied directories.
    AssemblyResolver: Did not find assembly in user-supplied directories.
    AssemblyResolver: Attempting framework directory.
    AssemblyResolver: Did not find assembly in framework directory.
AssemblyResolver: Unable to resolve reference. (It still might be found, e.g., in the GAC.)
AssemblyResolver: Assembly 'NHibernate.Validator' is referencing assembly 'System.Core'.
    AssemblyResolver: Attempting referencing assembly's directory.
    AssemblyResolver: Did not find assembly in referencing assembly's directory.
    AssemblyResolver: Attempting input directory.
    AssemblyResolver: Did not find assembly in input directory.
    AssemblyResolver: Attempting user-supplied directories.
Resolved assembly reference 'System.Core' to 'C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll'. (Used a client-supplied directory.)
Can not find PDB file. Debug info will not be available for assembly 'System.Core'.
AssemblyResolver: Assembly 'NHibernate.Validator' is referencing assembly 'log4net'.
    AssemblyResolver: Attempting referencing assembly's directory.
Can not find PDB file. Debug info will not be available for assembly 'log4net'.
Resolved assembly reference 'log4net' to 'C:\Dev\Dev\2010\Shared Libraries\Third Party\Sharp Architecture\lib\log4net.dll'. (Used referencing Module's directory.)
AssemblyResolver: Assembly 'NHibernate' is referencing assembly 'Iesi.Collections'.
    AssemblyResolver: Attempting referencing assembly's directory.
Resolved assembly reference 'Iesi.Collections' to 'C:\Dev\Dev\2010\Shared Libraries\Third Party\Sharp Architecture\lib\Fluent NHibernate\Iesi.Collections.dll'. (Used referencing Module's directory.)
AssemblyResolver: Assembly 'NHibernate' is referencing assembly 'System.ServiceModel'.
    AssemblyResolver: Attempting referencing assembly's directory.
    AssemblyResolver: Did not find assembly in referencing assembly's directory.
    AssemblyResolver: Attempting input directory.
    AssemblyResolver: Did not find assembly in input directory.
    AssemblyResolver: Attempting user-supplied directories.
Resolved assembly reference 'System.ServiceModel' to 'C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.ServiceModel.dll'. (Used a client-supplied directory.)
Can not find PDB file. Debug info will not be available for assembly 'System.ServiceModel'.
AssemblyResolver: Assembly 'NHibernate' is referencing assembly 'System.Transactions'.
    AssemblyResolver: Attempting referencing assembly's directory.
    AssemblyResolver: Did not find assembly in referencing assembly's directory.
    AssemblyResolver: Attempting input directory.
    AssemblyResolver: Did not find assembly in input directory.
    AssemblyResolver: Attempting user-supplied directories.
    AssemblyResolver: Did not find assembly in user-supplied directories.
    AssemblyResolver: Attempting framework directory.
Can not find PDB file. Debug info will not be available for assembly 'System.Transactions'.
Resolved assembly reference 'System.Transactions' to 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\..\v2.0.50727\System.Transactions.dll'. (Used framework directory.)
Using assembly 'NHibernate.Validator' for assembly-level attributes for the target assembly.
Merging assembly 'NHibernate.Validator' into target assembly.
Assembly level attribute 'System.Security.AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute' from assembly 'NHibernate.Validator' being deleted from target assembly
Merging assembly 'NHibernate' into target assembly.
Duplicate type name: modifying name of the type '<>f__AnonymousType0`2' (from assembly 'NHibernate') to 'NHibernate.<>f__AnonymousType0`2'
Duplicate type name: modifying name of the type '<>f__AnonymousType1`2' (from assembly 'NHibernate') to 'NHibernate.<>f__AnonymousType1`2'
Duplicate type name: modifying name of the type '<>f__AnonymousType2`2' (from assembly 'NHibernate') to 'NHibernate.<>f__AnonymousType2`2'
Duplicate type name: modifying name of the type '<>f__AnonymousType3`2' (from assembly 'NHibernate') to 'NHibernate.<>f__AnonymousType3`2'
Duplicate type name: modifying name of the type '<>f__AnonymousType4`2' (from assembly 'NHibernate') to 'NHibernate.<>f__AnonymousType4`2'
Assembly level attribute 'System.Security.AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute' from assembly 'NHibernate' being deleted from target assembly
Copying 1 Win32 Resources from assembly 'NHibernate.Validator' into target assembly.
ILMerge: Signing assembly with the key file 'SharpArch.Core\SharpArch.snk'.
    There were no errors reported in the target assembly's metadata.
ILMerge: Writing target assembly 'SharpArchitecture.dll'.
An exception occurred during merging:
Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: NHibernate.
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetAssemblyRefIndex(AssemblyNode assembly)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetTypeRefIndex(TypeNode type)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitReferencedType(TypeNode type)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitMethodCall(MethodCall call)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitAssignmentStatement(AssignmentStatement assignment)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitBlock(Block block)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitBlock(Block block)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitMethodBody(Method method)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitMethod(Method method)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitClass(Class Class)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitModule(Module module)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.SetupMetadataWriter(String debugSymbolsLocation)
   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.WritePE(Module module, String debugSymbolsLocation, BinaryWriter writer)
   at System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(String location, Boolean writeDebugSymbols, Module module, Boolean delaySign, String keyFileName, String keyName)
   at System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(CompilerParameters compilerParameters, Module module)
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: What's the underlying problem? Why are you trying to merge NHibernate (and with what other DLLs)? NHibernate already runs on .net 3.5. How is Sharepoint involved?

Comment: the underlying problem is having a zillion dlls to register in the gac for sharepoint - maintaining loads of web.configs that need to reference them all. when you add up the dependency between NH, Sharp Architecture and our own projects, there's a lot. Why was ILMerge written? I have mentioned 3.5 as its sharepoint - there are posts on how to target v4 which are not relevant

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax instead:

```
ILMerge.exe /log:"merge.txt" /lib:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5" /lib:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0" /lib:"FullPathToNHibernate" /lib:"FullPathToFluent NHibernate" /out:SharpArchitectureMerged.dll SharpArchitecture.dll NHibernate.Validator.dll NHibernate.dll /keyfile:"SharpArch.Core\SharpArch.snk"
```

Basically,
1. Pass the output assembly in /out
2. The primary assembly is the first parameter after the /out switch
3. Pass the full library paths using the /lib switch

**OR** you can provide the full file paths of the referenced assemblies like this:

```
ILMerge.exe /log:"merge.txt" /lib:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5" /lib:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0" /out:SharpArchitectureMerged.dll SharpArchitecture.dll "FullPathToNHibernate\NHibernate.Validator.dll" "FullPathToFluent NHibernate\NHibernate.dll" /keyfile:"SharpArch.Core\SharpArch.snk"
```

I'm thinking that your current directory does not resolve the partial path references, etc.

NHibernate.Validator.dll could also be looking for specific strongly named version of NHibernate.dll.